# Gas estimation failed | Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (16966)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix-ide

Iam trying to deploy a contract on erc20, the code can be compiled without any problem and i deployed it on testnet as well without any problem but when i try and switch to mainnet iam getting this error.

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (15854)

Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Iam trying to deploy a contract on erc20, the code can be compiled without any problem and i deployed it on testnet as well without any problem but when i try and switch to mainnet iam getting Gas estimation failed | Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (16966)

Comment: You might want to post the code or link to it, otherwise this is guess work